# Looping query over multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to scan two tables (all rows where the name matches), and then I need to find the MAXIMUM difference in the sell and buy prices. (highest profit that could be made)

How can I find this result strictly using mysql? I want the query to perform the calculation.

I have two tables:

SELL:

```
Name   | Sell_price | Seller
------------------------
Toyota | 12,000     | Mike
Toyota | 11,000     | Tony
Toyota | 9,000      | James
----------------------------
Mazda  | 5,000      | Craig
Mazda  | 4,000      | Roger
Mazda  | 3,000      | Jones
```

Buy:

```
Name   | Buying_Price | Buyer
------------------------
Toyota | 13,000       | Steve
Toyota | 12,000       | Andy
Toyota | 10,000       | Charles
----------------------------
Mazda  | 5,000        | Thatguy
Mazda  | 4,000        | Dog
Mazda  | 3,500        | Cat
```

Result:

```
Name   |Profit |  Buyer  | Seller
----------------------------------
Toyota | 2,000 | Charles | Mike
---------------------------------
Mazda  | 1,500 | Craig   | Cat
```

Comment: Please show some sql code you've tried, the results you got and what you're missing.

Comment: I fail to see why you pick Charles and Mike for Toyota and not any of the other names. What is your rule for chosing rows per brand? And I fail to see what makes Craig a buyer and Cat a seller in your results. Is that a mistake or some additional logic? Apart from that: What is your actual problem? You certainly know how to select from tables, how to join, how to filter, how to aggregate, so what is it exactly where you need help?

Comment: @thorstenKettner That's because it is the greatest profit I could make for Toyota (Buy from charles), (sell to Mike) would give me 2,000 in profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables on brand and then filter to only get the maximum sell and minimum buying prices:

```
select 
  sell.name, 
  sell.sell_price - buy.buying_price as profit, 
  buy.buyer, 
  sell.seller
from sell
join buy on buy.name = sell.name
where (sell.name, sell.sell_price) in
(
  select name, max(sell_price)
  from sell
  group by name
)
and (buy.name, buy.buying_price) in
(
  select name, min(buying_price)
  from buy
  group by name
);
```

Or do it vice versa, filter first and then join:

```
select 
  s.name, 
  s.sell_price - b.buying_price as profit, 
  b.buyer, 
  s.seller
from
(
  select *
  from sell
  where (name, sell_price) in
  (
    select name, max(sell_price)
    from sell
    group by name
  )
) s
join
(
  select * 
  from buy
  where (name, buying_price) in
  (
    select name, min(buying_price)
    from buy
    group by name
  )
) b on b.name = s.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare every row against every other row, so [`OUTER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html) is your friend. Then you can do a calculation in your `SELECT` and use [`AS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to assign a temporary column name:

```
SELECT s.name, (s.sell_price - b.buy_price) AS profit, s.seller, b.buyer 
FROM `sell` as s
OUTER JOIN `buy` as b ON s.name=b.name
```

To then sort it, you simply need to utilize `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT s.name, (s.sell_price - b.buy_price) AS profit, s.seller, b.buyer 
FROM `sell` as s
OUTER JOIN `buy` as b ON s.name=b.name
ORDER BY profit
```

You are probably right not to do this in code, depending on your context.

Comment: how does this find the highest profit #, as in the max(buy_price) - min(sell_price) for every car name.

Comment: @Edward Should it? That wasn't actually stated in the question.

Comment: Sorry you're right but yea i need to get the biggest difference price which is why it's not a simple query i believe

Comment: Do you need it per `name` or simply overall? These are details that are useful to include in the question!

Comment: per each name, take a look at what the result table should look like, something like for toyota in table A check when it is Toyota in table B then find the minimum price in table B and maximum price in table A and save into profit.

Comment: That is somewhat more complicated, and I'd have to play around with it more. Update your question with correct details, along with fixing your output, as noted?

Comment: Yes I believe I will need to use a stored procedure I will update question

Comment: I don't think you do, just a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (not tested):

Select s.sell_price - b.buyer_price from seller as s join buyer as b on s.name like b.name group by s.name, b.name;

Answer (score 1):

A little bit modified query but I suppose that it's giving more precise result.
If You are making calculating of your proffit as a seller, then You have to select only rows where the buying price is greater then the selling price.

```
SELECT s.name, s.sell_price, b.buy_price, (b.buy_price - s.sell_price) AS proffit, s.seller, b.buyer 
FROM `sell` as s
RIGHT JOIN `buy` as b ON s.name=b.name WHERE b.buy_price > s.sell_price ORDER BY proffit DESC
```

and the result will be:

```
name    |  proffit   |   seller  |   buyer
--------------------------------------------
Toyota  |  4,000     |   James   |   Steve   
Mazda   |  2,000     |   Jones   |   Thatguy
Toyota  |  1,000     |   James   |   Charlie
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your result table, u need to retrieve only records which have profits without any damages. You can try like this one.

```
SELECT s.Name, (s.Sell_Price-b.Buying_Price) AS Profit, b.Buyer, s.Seller
FROM Sell s RIGHT JOIN Buy b ON s.Name=b.Name 
WHERE b.Buying_Price > s.Sell_Price;
```